# VSCode get stucked while creating new Angular project?

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am trying to create a new project of Angular using

```
ng new projectname
```

but the problem is it get stucked. I have tried 3 times but it always get stucked. Is there any way to do it fast for example by skipping something in installation.
Here is the screen shot:

[image]

Please suggest something. Thanks for help.

Comment: Try run this on CMD or in Git console. You can also try reinstall angular-cli.

Answer (score -1):

For those who also looking for the solution for the same, plz try this it's working :

**ng new projectname --skip-npm**